# DS1307 based ardunio clock running three time faster

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, clock, crystal

Yesterday I observed my clock was running 10 min faster. I performed sketch burning process for sync time again from PC. But this time date/time was not syncing with PC time and the **clock was running three times faster**. I have performed all troubleshooting steps. What can I can? Rechecked wiring circuit, replaced crystal DS1307 chip, battery, fixed crystal body to ground etc. Even tried different version of code also. On serial monitor I have found wrong date/time is printing and two different value of date/time showing like:

```
0:8:23 Date 31 (Wrong time and day)
165:166:342 Date 232 (Not able to understand what is this)
```

There are two problems I am facing:

1. Clock running three time faster. This case clock is not usable for me
2. Date/Time not syncing with PC time after burning sketch

You can check [my video which shows the clock running very fast](https://youtu.be/JxhtqnobwhE). Here's the [photo album](https://photos.google.com/u/1/share/AF1QipMMUaFD0StJG9CDjFB55GEf2hR3gJ1Cuf7AW-CKZTWj9dGcsvQofFVZzz_l4hKULw?key=eFNpbkVKNTZPcDYxZGNFZHk5OHo4NUN3ZlU2X3F3).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post your schematics and your code?

Comment: You might compare your hardware and code with this [similar adafruit project](https://learn.adafruit.com/ds1307-real-time-clock-breakout-board-kit/overview) that also uses the ds1307.  You may see differences in the code or the hardware that might help you find the source of your problem.

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's nothing we can do to help you. - Except suggesting that the problem probably *is* in your code.

Answer (score 0):

it's fixed..
i have performed below action:

```
Changed crystal

Make ground to crystal and given more space on PCB for paste
horizontally

Added some glue to crystal for paste in PCB

Added more wire for shorten path to battery ground

I was doing mistake while time sync that keeping power off to DS1307
circuit while sketch uploading to Ardunio mini by FTDI uploaded.
After power on DS1307 circuit while sketch uploading now time sync
properly with PC.

Added 22pf bypass caps to crystal legs.
```